# SOAP non-WSDL mode / PHP

Tags: php, soap

Добрый день.
Помогите пожалуйста составить запрос используя SoapClient
Я только с wsdl работал..., а с этим режимом впервые встречаюсь

**Пример запроса в формате SOAP 1.2**

POST http://soap.server.ua

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

Content-Length: length

SOAPAction: http://soap.server.ua/API#GetToken

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetToken xmlns="http://soap.server.ua/API">
         <login xsi:type="xsd:string">user</login>
         <password xsi:type="xsd:string">********</password>
      </GetToken>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Пример ответа в формате SOAP 1.2**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetTokenResponse xmlns="http://soap.server.ua/API">
         <Session>
            <hash xsi:type="xsd:string">khfjadh334ghjg3g3hg2h3g2jjgh2jj3</hash>
            <session_id xsi:type="xsd:string">D7sfJ83lKP2o9Utr8ww21ZaJqqP34Sax</session_id>
         </Session>
      </GetTokenResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Добавьте реальный url вместо http://soap.server.ua

Comment: Реальный url ничего не даст. Там доступ еще по IP ограничен

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, это можно отправить с помощью cURL.

```
$data = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetToken xmlns="http://soap.server.ua/API">
            <login xsi:type="xsd:string">user</login>
            <password xsi:type="xsd:string">********</password>
        </GetToken>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
$ch = curl_init("http://soap.server.ua");
curl_setopt_array(
    $ch,
    array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    => true,
        CURLOPT_POST              => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS        => $data,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER        => array(
            'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Length: '.strlen($data),
            'SOAPAction: http://soap.server.ua/API#GetToken',
        )
    )
);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$retXml = simplexml_load_string($res);
```

Comment: Обычный пост запрос всегда можно отправить. Необходимо решение с использованием SOAP

Comment: Я пробывал
http://pastebin.com/QN2vqBZz

Отдает ошибку
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Sender] encodingStyle cannot be specified on the Envelope in /var/www/dev/data/supervisor/worker/warehouse/1.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/dev/data/supervisor/worker/warehouse/1.php(21): SoapClient->__soapCall('GetToken', Array, Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/dev/data/supervisor/worker/warehouse/1.php on line 21